# Convert google sheet Row and column in JSON using app script

Tags: google-sheets, sourceforge-appscript

Is there any way to convert this=> [google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpIBo.png) into the below given JSON object using AppScript. I'm new to AppScript I dont have idea how to make this row and column in the below given object. Thanks in advance.

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "insurer":"CompanyName1",
         "products":[
            {
               "name":"product1",
               "UIN":"104N079V01"
            },
            {
               "name":"product2",
               "UIN":"104N079V02"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "insurer":"CompanyName2",
         "products":[
            {
               "name":"product1",
               "UIN":"104N079V01"
            },
            {
               "name":"product2",
               "UIN":"104N079V02"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: pls, share the data in a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function data2json() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var values = sh.getRange('A1').getDataRegion().getValues()
  // Logger.log(values)
  var jsn = {}
  jsn['data'] = []
  var n = -1
  var m = 0
  values.forEach(function (r, i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      if (r[1] != '') {
        n++
        jsn['data'][n] = {}
        jsn['data'][n]['insurer'] = r[1]
        jsn['data'][n]['products'] = []
        m = -1
      }
      m++
      jsn['data'][n]['products'][m] = {}
      jsn['data'][n]['products'][m]['name'] = r[2]
      jsn['data'][n]['products'][m]['UIN'] = r[3]
    }
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(jsn))
}
```

example

[image]

result

```
{"data":[{"insurer":"CompanyName1","products":[{"name":"product1","UIN":"A"},{"name":"product2","UIN":"B"},{"name":"product3","UIN":"C"},{"name":"product4","UIN":"D"}]},{"insurer":"CompanyName2","products":[{"name":"product5","UIN":"E"},{"name":"product6","UIN":"F"},{"name":"product7","UIN":"G"},{"name":"product8","UIN":"H"}]},{"insurer":"CompanyName3","products":[{"name":"product9","UIN":"I"},{"name":"product10","UIN":"J"},{"name":"product11","UIN":"K"}]}]}
```